# Why doesn't the quantum eraser violate the no-deletion theorem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, double-slit-experiment, information, quantum-eraser

In the [quantum eraser experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_eraser_experiment) and its variants, you basically have a double slit experiment, where you detect which slit the photon went through, but then forget this information.

My question is, why doesn't this contradict the [Quantum no-deleting theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_no-deleting_theorem)?

Note: Okay, so have two slits and a detector. You send a photon towards the detector. The photon will go through one or the other, and you detect this. Then you delete this information. The photon creates an interference pattern. Why was the deletion possible? (The link has a more specific setup, but I want the question to be for quantum eraser experiments in general).

Comment: Because it is a theorem?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Well, yeah. I guess the question is more precisely stated as "why does it look like the quantum eraser is deleting information, when is in fact not (via the no-deletion theorem)?"

Comment: @NorbertSchuch (But yes. Since it is a theorem, and the quantum eraser is a real experiment, and the quantum eraser didn't invalidate the foundations of quantum mechanics, the experiment didn't violate the no-deletion theorem.)

Comment: Well, if you would describe more precisely the setup and which point exactly you find puzzling, it would be easier to provide a to-the-point answer. In any case, the answer will be subjective, so you will need to provide input if you want a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I explained it a little more.

Comment: If you ask "Why was deletion possible", then you should also ask "Why was getting this information possible" in the first place.  It's two sides of the same coin.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. The Wikipedia article you link to explicitly starts with two copies of the same state. How does this apply to the quantum eraser, where there is only ever a single copy?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Yes, I was thinking that. I sort of wanted to make the question minimal, I suppose. There are both paradoxical to me though.

Comment: Copying quantum information *in a classical basis* is completely fine (e.g. using a CNOT and a $\vert0\rangle$ ancilla), and this is basically the same.

Comment: The cool thing about this is that you never actually detected which slit the photon went trough because photons don't go anywhere... so you are basically just discussing the finer points of your own misinterpretation of the experiment. :-)

Answer (score 3):

## Because they're talking about two completely different things.

- The quantum no-deletion theorem tells you that there is no linear unitary transformation $U$ that will take two copies of the same state in a tensor product, $|\psi⟩\otimes|\psi⟩$, and turn one of them into a pre-specified blank, i.e.
  $$U|\psi⟩\otimes|\psi⟩=|\psi⟩\otimes|\mathrm{blank}⟩.$$
- The quantum eraser takes information in the form of *entanglement* (i.e. not a single-partite quantum state, much less two of them), of the form
  $$|\mathrm{up}⟩\otimes|{↑}⟩+|\mathrm{down}⟩\otimes|{↓}⟩,$$
  where $|{↑}⟩$ and $|{↓}⟩$ are the states of the photon after it's gone through the 'up' or the 'down' slit and $|\mathrm{up}⟩$ and $|\mathrm{down}⟩$ are the states of the apparatus that records this information, and then removes that entanglement (by performing a projective measurement on $|\mathrm{up}⟩ \pm |\mathrm{down}⟩$) in a way that restores the coherence in the photon.

## The two formalisms don't contradict each other because they have nothing to do with each other.

I think this is a terrible, ill-researched question, but [the community user keeps bringing it back up](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/228687/revisions) and someone just needed to say this to put the matter to rest.

Answer (score 0):

The delayed choice quantum eraser doesn't delete a qubit, it measures an entangled qubit along a parallel axis or else along a perpendicular axis.

As an analogy, suppose Alice and Bob share an EPR pair $\left| 01 \right\rangle - \left| 10 \right\rangle$. Alice measures her qubit from the pair along the Z axis. Now, Bob could also measure along the Z axis, which would tell him Alice's result. Alternatively, he could measure along a perpendicular axis such as the X axis and learn nothing about Alice's result. Or he could measure along some intermediate axis and get partial information. Or he could not measure at all or throw away the qubit, and also learn nothing.

The same basic thing happens in the delayed choice experiment as in the EPR pair choosing-to-measure-the-correlated-axis experiment. Bob either measures along the axis needed to recover the information that splits Alice's apparent lack-of-interference pattern into two complementary interference patterns ("erasing"), or he doesn't.

[image: Alice always sees the same thing]

Comment: One question I am not clear, in this setup,  we have two 'events', the measurement of 'which path' and the detection of the interference pattern. Are they spacelike or timelike separated? Since one debate on this is the causality. Thanks.

Comment: Or I may just ask the question: If the 'delayed erasure' action E happens 1 second after the interference pattern detection action P, what will we get at P in the first 1 second of the experiment?

Comment: @X.Dong Alice always sees no interference pattern, regardless of what Bob has done. It's only when you use Bob's measurement results to group Alice's results that each sub-group can show the complementary interference patterns.

Comment: Thanks, I read your blog article and it's clear for me now. Is it true that even the erasure is not delayed, still we can not observe the interference pattern?

Comment: @X.Dong As soon as the which-way qubit exists, you should never see an interference pattern. Every eraser experiment must condition Alice's results on Bob's to recover any interference pattern (e.g. by only counting runs where Bob's photon made it through a vertical polarizer as in http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0106078v1.pdf ). (I guess you could also restore the pattern by doing unitary stuff like un-making the EPR pair, but I wouldn't classify experiments that perform quantum operations on the photon pair as "erasers"; more like "nevermind let's not do anything interesting"-ers.)